# How to add the html content into this Sendgrid's code?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

There have been some updates to the SendGrid-PHP library. See the example from the readme : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

```html
<?php
// If you are using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// If you are not using Composer (recommended)
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@example.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "test@example.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

I want to add html content, not instead of the plain text, how to change the code?

Answer (score 2):

To be abel to send html , this line :

```
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
```

must be as follows:

```
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hello, Email!");
//                                    ^^^^
```

for more details , checkout this [example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.php)

---

#### Update

to manually send mixed html and plain text emails :

```
$boundary = uniqid('np');
$content = new SendGrid\Content("multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary, "Hello, Email!");
```

Comment: If I change to "text/html", the email will be alert that "Message only has text/html MIME parts".

so, I want to add the html and the plain text together, how to write the code?

Comment: to do though , there will be much work around to do, you may contact the package author to implement an easy method to make you able to do that;

Comment: @davidfnck check my updated answer, i'm not sure if this try will work properly or not, if not so you will have to contact the package author as i said